# Regular expression to remove all spaces

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to remove everything inside the "( )" and all spaces in java with regrex I am close here is the string

```
First Last "(Some stuff)"
```

And here is my regrex

```
\s\"\([^)]*\)\"
```

the only thing it doesnt do it remove the space between first and last?

How can I add that?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use altenration to match text inside `(..)` or spaces:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"\\([^)]*\\)\"|\\s+", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OEYf6i/1)

Comment: The string `Test: "(this is (c) copyright me)" :End` will fail to *remove everything inside the "( )"*, using that regex. This regex works: `"\(.*?\)"|\s+`

Comment: @Andreas: Yes if there are cases of nested parentheses then `\(.*?\)` shoud work.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * remove any spaces such as:<br>
 * (<b>\n</b>, <b>\t</b> <b>System.lineSeparator()</b>, <b>\r</b>)...etc
 * */
public static String killSpaces(String str) throws Exception {
    return str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```

Comment: OP wants to *remove everything inside the `"( )"`*. This answer fails to do that.